# Save modified image as a direct copy via scripting API

Tags: python, scripting, image

So it turns out pre-processing some image data in Blender is fairly non-trivial and unfruitful task without extra libraries. If I modify raw pixels (pixels prop on BlendDataImages object) Blender wont update the view with them when using as a part of  material nodes/texture source (only in ImageViewer, which is pointless). I also can't use save() even if I wanted to, for some reason it never works and been broken for ages, as search on this SE sub-resource shows (also, it is DDS and Blender cant write DDS). I *could* save it as a render frame but because it uses scene render settings it always will be off in colors, even if you match the output format as close as possible to source (in this case DDS, saving as PNG or TGA or Iris or EXR). There is no way for me to match the rest of render_settings 1:1 because user can have **whatever** set up.
You could use 'save_as_a_copy' but this fails for pre-processing because it requires user dialogue and interaction (I never found a way to do it behind the scenes)

If anyone knows some other ways I've missed - let me know. The idea is to load image, flip pixels, **save as 1:1 copy** and replace. Bolded step is where it all ded.

My current approach is rather ugly:

```py
image.pixels[:] = do_a_flip()
image.update()
image.pack()
image.reload()
image.unpack()
```

Comment: Is your goal to update image.pixels and have the 3D view update? That works for me automatically.

Comment: Which version of the blender? I need to support 2.8+ and updating raw pixel data only update ImageViewer

Comment: 2.92. Works for me testing from the Python console.

Comment: Yeah, may be it was fixed later. Guess I will use workaround for 2.8 only, thanks!

Comment: (OT, but you may also be interested to know that 2.83 added image.pixels.foreach_set(...), which is absurdly faster than image.pixels[:] = ...)

Comment: Already saw the thread where the issue was raised. Yeah, I know it.